# Can AWS SAM add new serverless functions to an existing imported API Gateway resource via Fn::ImportValue function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

Can AWS Serverless Application Model (SAM) add new functions to an existing API Gateway resource imported via Fn::ImportValue function into the current stack?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not possible. To expose Lambda Functions via API Gateway in SAM, the API Gateway must be created in the same SAM template.
You can use the [CloudFormation Import Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) to reference a resource attribute or output from another stack but you can not add methods.

That is a limitation of SAM and there are more details about that in this [discussion](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/discussions/2734) but without expectations on a near solution date.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add new functions to API Gateway Apis created in other stacks ***if*** your API Gateway were created using `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi`.

You'll need to import the ***ApiGateway Id*** and ***RootResourceId*** attributes to your SAM template and create the ApiGatewayMethod for each integration and a deployment for your Api.

Reference:

- [AWS::Serverless::Api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html)
- [Fn::ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html)